# How to split a string by using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

```
length 10 cm width 2 cm depth 0.5 cm / length 10 cm width 2 depth 0.5 cm
```

I want to get output like

```
length 10 cm
width 2 cm / width 2
depth 0.5 cm
```

I tried this

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    String s = "length 10 cm width 2 cm depth 0.5 cm";
    String[] tok = s.split("(?<=\\d)\\s");
    for(int i=0; i< tok.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(tok[i]);
    }
}
```

It returns:

```
length 10
cm width 2
cm depth 0.5
cm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following *match pattern*.

```
(?: (?<![/*+-] )(?=length|width|depth))
```

Output

```
length 10 cm
width 2 cm
depth 0.5 cm / length 10 cm
width 2
depth 0.5 cm
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your regex to match the correct result correctly:

here is a sample code that comes with your desired output

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "length 10 cm width 2 cm depth 0.5 cm";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+\\s\\d+\\.?\\d*\\s\\w+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

And the output would be:

```
length 10 cm
width 2 cm
depth 0.5 cm
```

For getting more information on the regex, you can use [Regex 101 Site](https://regex101.com/) and put the string and the regex to get the explanation.

**Update 1**

To achieve the dynamic solution the below code can help you in this case you need to determine the units as well. I assume you have `cm` and `mm` for more units you need to add them to the regex.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "length 10 cm width 2 depth 0.5 cm extra 5 mm";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\w+\s\d+\.?\d*(\s(cm|mm))?)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

the output would be:

```
length 10 cm
width 2
depth 0.5 cm
extra 5 mm
```

Comment: Thank you Ali Malik, Can you please help me,  With any possible dynamic solution for  this input "length 10 cm width 2 depth 0.5 cm"

Comment: @srkprasad What do you mean by dynamic solution? If you give more examples it would be good.

Comment: Sometimes we don't add units (cm), Given input text like "length 10 width 2 depth 0.5 cm", I want output like                          
length 10
width 2
depth 0.5 cm

Comment: if you always use `cm` as the unit this regex will help you => `(\w+\s\d+\.?\d*(\scm)?)`. Otherwise, you need to add other units you have like `mm` and the regex would be => `(\w+\s\d+\.?\d*(\s(cm|mm))?)

Comment: @srkprasad See the **Update 1** section

Answer (score 1):

Splitting could lead to unexpected results if you also have other data, but for the example if you don't want to keep `depth 0.5 cm / length 10 cm` you could use:

```
\h(?=width|depth)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B9XO53/1)

The output after splitting:

```
length 10 cm
width 2 cm
depth 0.5 cm / length 10 cm
width 2
depth 0.5 cm
```

---

If you don't want to keep the  `/`  and have all the units on a separate line:

```
(?<=\bcm)\h[\h/]*|(?<=\d)\h+(?!cm\b)
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<=\bcm)` Positive lookbehind, assert that to the left is the word `cm`
- `\h[\h/]*` Match at least a single horizontal whitespace char followed by optional horizontal whitespace chars or `/`
- `|` Or
- `(?<=\d)` Assert that to the left is a digit
- `\h+` Match 1 or more horizontal whitspace chars
- `(?!cm\b)` Assert that the word `cm` is not to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VjE3tx/1)

Example

```
String s = "length 10 cm width 2 cm depth 0.5 cm / length 10 cm width 2 depth 0.5 cm";
String[] tok = s.split("(?<=\\bcm)\\h[\\h/]*|(?<=\\d)\\h+(?!cm\\b)");
for (int i = 0; i < tok.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(tok[i]);
}
```

Output

```
length 10 cm
width 2 cm
depth 0.5 cm
length 10 cm
width 2
depth 0.5 cm
```

---

But matching would allow for a more precise match, which you can adapt to match more unit types as needed.

**Note** to double escape the backslash in Java.

```
\b(?:leng|wid|dep)th\h+\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\h+cm)?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/93VgCr/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/fbf8x2)